# Objective-C - Don´t get access to an Object from another class

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

i have got a question. It would be great if somebody could help me.
I have a class myObject and a class HelloWorldLayer. In the HelloWorld i want to call a Method doSomething on myObjectX.

But with

```
[myObjectX doSomething];
```

it want not work.

Does anybody know a solution to do it this way??

How i have to call doSomething on myObjectX without to change the remaining code.

Thanks a lot.

```
myObject.h
@interface myObject : CCSprite {
}

-(void)doSomething;
@end

myObject.m
@implementation myObject

-(void)doSomething
{
    NSLog(@"test");
}
@end

HelloWorldLayer.h
@interface HelloWorldLayer : CCLayerGKLeaderboardViewControllerDelegate>
{
    CCSprite *myObjectX;
}
-(void)test;
@end

HelloWorldLayer.m
@implementation HelloWorldLayer
-(void)test
{
    myObjectX = [[myObject alloc]init];
    [myObjectX doSomething];
}
@end
```

Comment: Do you have #import "myObject.h" in your class HelloWorldLayer ?

Comment: Yes!! And the doSomething Method in -(void)drawMyObject works. But in the ccTouchBegan it doesn´t work.

Answer (score 1):

h

```
@interface HelloWorldLayer:CCLayer
{
    myObject *myObjectX;
}
```

Than you'll be able to call your myObjectX methods.

Comment: I tried this!! But than he tells me in the -(void)drawMyObject when i call [myObject doSomething]; "No visible @interface for 'CCSprite' declares the selector 'doSomething'

Comment: @user2343538: That message indicates that you're typing the instance variable as a CCSprite rather than a `myObject` like ProFFeSSoR is doing here.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
myObject *myObjectX = [[myObject1 alloc]init];
```

into

```
myObject1 *myObjectX = [[myObject1 alloc]init];
```

because `-(void)doSomething;` is declared in your `myObject1` and `myObject2` classes.

That's exactly what the message says : you got no `-(void)doSomething;` in your `myObject` class.

Or you could add :

```
@interface myObject:CCSprite
{

}
-(void)doSomething;    // Add here and implement in your .m
@end
```

Hope this helps.

**EDIT :**

You did this wrong :

```
@interface HelloWorldLayer : CCLayerGKLeaderboardViewControllerDelegate>
{
    CCSprite *myObjectX;
}
-(void)test;
@end
```

Correct it with this :

```
@interface HelloWorldLayer : myObject <CCLayerGKLeaderboardViewControllerDelegate>
{
}
@end
```

**A Priori**, you could use `doSomething` in `HelloWorldLayer` because it inherits from `myObject`.

Comment: Thanks for your help! i cant change it. cause i have a random in it where he choose myObject1 or myObject2 and write it in myObjectX. I tried the second way but i want not work. I have a problem to understand whats going wrong. I edit my code above in a more simple example... What i have to do to call doSomething on myObjectX in the test Method.i hope anybody could tell me. Thanks

Comment: Edited my answer relative to your comment. Hope this helps :)